# First Roll of Yahtzee Game, having trouble using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

The goal of this assignment is to just to display the probabilities of scoring on the first rolls (which is why I have a final int TRIALS, to later calculate the probability). I just need help creating the separate method for rolling the five dice using an array. I will be able to figure out the other methods, I just am confused with how to use arrays for something like this. Here is what I have so far (just the base outline to start):

```
final int TRIALS = 1_000_000;

    int yahtzee = 0;
    int fourKind = 0;
    int largeStraight = 0;
    int fullHouse = 0;
    int smallStraight = 0;
    int threeKind = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {

    }
}

public static int rollDice(int TRIALS) {

}
```

I am very much a beginner, and do not want a full solution, I just need help getting started with using the array. I know I will need random numbers (rand.nextInt(6)+1). But mainly, I just need help with my rollDice method.

Comment: What kind of integer is this `1_000_000`

Comment: It just means 1,000,000(1 million) the underscores are just to make it look better visually as opposed to putting 1000000

Comment: I frankly think you’re better off studying a tutorial on arrays, like for instance [the official one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), than asking a question here and read what comments and perhaps answers happen to come in.

Comment: If after trying some of the stuff from the array tutorial you have questions, I bet they’ll be a lot more specific and hence much better suited for Stackoverflow. Talk to you then. :-)

Comment: it seems you are going beyond your goal. The probability of scoring on the first role is always the same and should take one formula to calculate.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson nope. calculating the probabilities of getting each of the different kinds of scores on the first roll.

Comment: @OleV.V. not sure how I can make my question more specific....all I want to know is how to simulate rolling the array of five dice.

Comment: I, on the other hand, don’t know what it is you don’t know. Declare an array of 5 `int`s. Fill a die roll into each element.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, there are more ways to get (approximate or theoretical) probabilities. If you’re string in combinatorics, you can find the formulae for the theoretical probabilities. Another approach is to simulate the dice rolls and count. This has the further advantage of giving more programming experience. Yet another option: there are 7776 possible rolls of 5 dice. You may iterate through them to get more accurate probablitites than you get with random rolls.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. I know.

Comment: There are some probablitites on http://datagenetics.com/blog/january42012/ (and no doubt other places in the net). I don’t know if looking there would count as cheating…

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your last comment.

```
int[] roll5DiceEachOnce()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] dice = new int[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dice[i] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("die " + i + ": " + dice[i]);//just so you can see the output 
    }

    return dice;
}
```